# How does equating to zero the coefficients of lowest degree terms in x and y give the tangent at origin to a polynomial curve?

Tags: derivatives, algebraic-curves, tangent-line

My course book on differential calculus says, "... the equation of the tangent at the origin can be written down by equating to zero the lowest degree terms in x and y."
I don't see how this is true.

Why is this true ?

Comment: '' the lowest degree terms'' of what?

Comment: Sorry. I've edited the question now.

Comment: A term to search for is "tangent cone".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the curve be $$f(x)=g(y)$$

Assuming that $f(\cdot), g(\cdot)$ are polynomials, the respective constant terms must be zero such that the curve passes through the origin.

Differentiating w.r.t $x$ gives
$$f'(x)+g'(y)\frac {dy}{dx}=0\\\frac {dy}{dx}=-\frac {f'(x)}{g'(y)}$$
Hence slope at origin is $-\dfrac{f'(0)}{g'(0)}$ 
and tangent at origin is
$$y=-\frac {f'(0)}{g'(0)}x\\
\color{red}{f'(0)\ x+g'(0)\ y=0}$$

---

NB:

If $f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1 x+a_0$, then $f'(0)\ x = a_1 x$ which is the lowest term in $x$ in $f(x)$. Similarly for $g(y)$.

Instruction should read
"...by equating to zero the **sum of** the lowest degree terms in $x$ and $y$."

Note that, assuming $g'(0)\neq 0$, if $f(x)$ does not have an $x$ term then the tangent at the origin must have a slope of zero i.e. the $x$-axis is the tangent at the origin.